# INNER JOIN doesn't work with Primary Key

Tags: sqlite, inner-join, primary-key

I have table1:

```
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
NAME_ID - INTEGER REFERENCES table2(ID),
SOME_TEXT TEXT NOT NULL;
```

and table2:

```
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
NAME TEXT NOT NULL,
SOME_NUMBER INTEGER;
```

SOME_NUMBER is the same as table2.ID. I would like to get output like:
table1.ID, table1.some_text, table2.name
and it should go with code like:

```
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT table1.id, table1.some_text, table2.name "
            + "FROM table1 "
            + "INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.name_id = table2.id;" );
```

Output is empty in this case, but if I change table2.id to table2.some_number in the last line it provides me a good result.
This problem comes with all tables combination I tried with INNER JOIN on Primary Key.

Please help me guys.

Comment: Please show your full DDL, input table values, expected output and actual output for your two queries. Read about [mcve]s.

Comment: Original code doesn't matter. I've posted a easier example of the same problem - most names and variables in my code are in my national language and it would be hard-to-read for international community here.

Comment: Nobody asked for the original code. We want to see the data.

Answer (score -1):

This is not exactly problem solvation, but I changed my database from SQLite to Apache Derby, and the same code works perfectly.